# gestureRecognizerShouldBegin on Subview Blocking Gestures on Parent CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit

I am having trouble with the following subview blocking gestures on its parent views:

```
class Circle: UIControl, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    
    let circle = CAShapeLayer()
    let radius: CGFloat = 15
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        let circleCenter = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)
        let path = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: circleCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: 0, endAngle: 2 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        circle.path = path.cgPath
        circle.frame = self.bounds
        layer.addSublayer(circle)
        
        let gesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Circle.handleTap(_:)))
        addGestureRecognizer(gesture)
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ selector: Any) {
        print("Here")
    }
    
    override func gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        let location = gestureRecognizer.location(in: self)
        let center = circle.position
        let circleFrame = CGRect(x: center.x - radius, y: center.y - radius, width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2)
        return circleFrame.contains(location)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I'm including this Circle view above on the following subclasses of `UICollectionViewController` (which has paging enabled and full screen cells) and `UICollectionViewCell` as shown in the code below:

```
class ViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    let cellId = "cell"
    let dataSource: [UIColor] = [.blue, .purple, .brown, .green, .red]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.isPagingEnabled = true
        collectionView.register(CellSubclass.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! CellSubclass
        cell.backgroundColor = dataSource[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    }
}

class CellSubclass: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        let circle = Circle(frame: self.bounds)
        addSubview(circle)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

I want the gesture on the subview Circle only to be handled when the circle is tapped on. (In my use case, the circle will be moving around the screen. This is a simplified example). This code works to accomplish that purpose, but the gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:) method on Circle is blocking the parent(s) views' gestures and doesn't allow me to swipe through the pages of the collection view's cells.

When I remove that method, I'm able to swipe through the cells as expected. I'm not sure why a gesture method on a subview is propagating up to affect its parent views in this way, but I've attempted to add the method

```
optional func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, 
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool
```

to both classes returning true, with no success. Any help to understand what is happening and fix this would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully, someone will find how I solved this helpful. I initially thought the best way to handle this problem was with the `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin(_:)` method, but with a full screen cell, that method blocks other gestures. The way that allows me to accomplish what I was trying to do is by using the `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldReceive:)` method to filter the desired touch area to the recognizer I was creating. As follows:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
    let center = circle.position
    let circleFrame = CGRect(x: center.x - radius, y: center.y - radius, width: radius * 2, height: radius * 2)
    let status = circleFrame.contains(location)
    return status
}
```